# ¿Por qué es posible que algunas etiquetas de sección puedan ser hijas de etiquetas que no son de sección?

Tags: html5

Se supone que las etiquetas de sección dividen temáticamente cada pieza de información de la página. Un elemento `<nav>` puede ser hijo de un elemento `<header>`, así también section podría ser hijo de `<header>`.

Pero `<nav`> y `<section`> son elementos que dividen la página, ¿por qué no debería estar mal que elementos como ese estén dentro de un elemento que no divide la pagina?

¿No sería como tener un libro y en la zona en donde se coloca el título del capítulo (el `<header`>) se colocaran areas en donde hay capítulos enteros (`<section`> o `<nav`>)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debemos entender el carácter abierto de HTML, que nace como un sistema que permite ordenar y etiquetar diversos documentos, pero que en si mismo no nos obliga a hacerlo de una determinada forma. Su función es ordenar y dotar de sentido, nada mas.

Lo que dices tiene razón, y es responsabilidad del maquetador o diseñador el organizar estas etiquetas de una forma que tengan sentido y cumplan con su objetivo.

Ocurre lo mismo con cualquier lenguaje de programación, podemos escribir nuestro código de cualquier manera y mientras funcione dejarlo así, o podemos seguir unas normas y hacerlo legible y claro, lo cual ayudara a su futura comprensión y mantenimiento.